# How do you calculate the expected value of the sum of random variables?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

For instance, when trying to compute $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i]$ where $X_i \sim N(0,1)$, I input into Mathematica:

```
Expectation[Sum[x[i],{i, 1, 10}], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]
```

but, instead of getting 0, I get:

```
x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]+x[7]+x[8]+x[9]+x[10]
```

Why is it not simplifying to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need all the assumptions:

```
Expectation[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, 10}], Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, 10}]]
```

returning:

```
0
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about if I change the `10` to a general variable `n`? It no longer works. I.e. `Expectation[Sum[x[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], {i, 1, n}]]` fails

Comment: Use the associative property of addition: ````Sum[Expectation[x[i], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]],{i, 1, n}]````

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assuming that the variates are i.i.d., the distribution of the sum is normal

```
distSum[μ_, σ_, n_Integer?Positive] := Assuming[σ > 0,
  TransformedDistribution[
    Total[Array[x, n]],
    Array[x[#] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ] &, n]] //
    Simplify]

distSum[μ, σ, 10]

(* NormalDistribution[10 μ, Sqrt[10] σ] *)
```

The mean and variance are as expected

```
#[distSum[μ, σ, 10]] & /@ {Mean, Variance}

(* {10 μ, 10 σ^2} *)
```

When the `x[i]` are standard normal

```
#[distSum[0, 1, 10]] & /@ {Mean, Variance}

(* {0, 10} *)
```

For a general `n`, start by generating a sequence of means and variances

```
seq = Table[{Mean[distSum[μ, σ, n]],
    Variance[distSum[μ, σ, n]]},
   {n, 1, 10}];
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence

```
mean[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq[[All, 1]], n]

(* n μ *)

var[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq[[All, 2]], n]

(* n σ^2 *)

stdDev[n_] = Assuming[σ > 0, Sqrt[var[n]] // Simplify]

(* Sqrt[n] σ *)
```